# Nokogiri is returning to root element. Why?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm sorry, this seems like an off-topic question, but just give me 2 minutes. I'm probably missing a tiny detail, but I'm going crazy over this tiny piece of code:

```
parsed = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

fullmeta = parsed.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]')[0]
if fullmeta.inner_html.to_s.include? "image"
    meta = fullmeta.xpath('//span[4]')[0]
else
    meta = fullmeta.xpath('//span[3]')[0]
end

puts meta.inner_html                    # This seems fine
puts meta.xpath('//a[1]')[0].inner_html # !!!
```

The line marked with `!!!` is the culprit. Something is making that line re-do the XPath from the root element of `parsed`! I have that variable declared a couple XPaths before. What. is. going. on. here? I've been sitting on this code for like an hour! (DuckDuckGo'd half the Internet already)

If you want an XML, just use any FanFiction story page. I'm writing an API for that in rails, but that's not really an important fact here.

---

Just in case anyone tries it out with FanFiction, this is what I get:

```
Rated: <a class="xcontrast_txt" href="https://www.fictionratings.com/" target="rating">Fiction  T</a> - English - Humor/Adventure - Chapters: 15   - Words: 55,643 - Reviews: <a href="/r/12135694/">22</a> - Favs: 5 - Follows: 8 - Updated: <span data-xutime="1501553985">17h</span> - Published: <span data-xutime="1473081239">9/5/2016</span> - id: 12135694 
FanFiction
```

The last line should say `Fiction  T`

Comment: `//` means start from root. Maybe you want `/`

Comment: -_- Told ya I was missing a tiny detail. :P Thanks so much!

Comment: If you want to search the descendants of the `meta` node then use the path `descendant::a` or `.//a`. For child elements you simply need `a`.

Comment: Just a question: then why does it work until the `This seems fine` line? Given that it also has `//`

Comment: It doesn't. You're just lucky there aren't any other `span` elements.

Comment: Oh, okay, got it. Tested in Chrome's search thing, you're right. Thank you all for helping! Sometimes I just love SO. I mean, I rarely ask questions, but this whole site saves me a ton of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the full power of XPath often means you don't have to stop and iterate, you can just grab what you want directly with a single expression. This allows you to externalize, store in variables, or otherwise organize your expressions and maintain them more easily, even if the XML changes. With XPath you can even incorporate some logic in the expressions.

Are you trying to get the rating of a story? Note that there's a `target=rating` attribute, so you can key off of that, rather than counting `span` elements.

```
doc.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]/span/a[@target="rating"]/text()')

#=> "Fiction M"
```

Another thing I'd recommend is to use either HTTParty or Mechanize, if you aren't already. They have different strengths. HTTParty gives you an easy way to create a nice object-oriented client with fetching and parsing. Mechanize focuses on scraping but it has Nokogiri built in and you can access the underlying Nokogiri document and just start executing XPath on it.

**Edit:**
Adding a couple others from your comment below.

```
language = doc.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]/span[a[@target="rating"]]/text()').to_s.split(' - ')[1]
#=> "English"
```

Note that the brackets `[]` can be read as "which contains," so we are looking for the span *which contains* a link with a target of rating. This way you don't need to count spans, which is more brittle.

```
genres = doc.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]/span[a[@target="rating"]]/text()').to_s.split(' - ')[2].split('/')
#=> ["Humor", "Adventure"]

id = doc.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]/span[a[@target="rating"]]/text()').to_s.split(' - ')[5].split(': ')
#=> "12596791"

published = DateTime.strptime(doc.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]//span/@data-xutime').first.value, '%s')
#=> 2017-08-01T20:03:19+00:00
```

And so on. I recommend putting the XPaths in something like a hash so you can refer to the more descriptive `xpath_for[:rating]` instead of hardcoding them all throughout the code.

Comment: Hmm, those are gems that I seriously have to check out, but in the meantime, I'm not just looking for the rating. I'm sorry you took all the time making this answer, but I need that if statement cause I'm storing everything. Here: `attr_reader :id, :title, :author, :summary, :rating, :language, :genres, :characters, :words, :chapters, :reviews, :favs, :follows, :updated, :published`

Comment: Hey no problem, I figured you wanted more than the rating. My intent was to show you that you can have a single expression per item. Let me know (via another SO post) if you have problems constructing an XPath for any of those items.

Comment: Thanks, but I've got everything under control now :) I'm not an expert on XPath and extracting stuff from HTML markups, but I kinda got used to it by now. I'll mark your post as an answer in case it helps some people.

Comment: Hopefully my additions help